# bind data dynamically to p-table(column wise)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, p-table

I have a json data like following,and I am trying to present this data in the table format but unable to bind in the expected way. can someone please let me know if we can achieve this with p-table ?

here is what I am trying, but duplicate records can be seen row wise as let-car is loop thhrough the data.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-demo-9izgpx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

data:

```
   {
        Year: 2023,
        InputData: {
          OilProduction: 0,
          GasProduction: 0,
          NGLProduction: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        Year: 2024,
        InputData: {
          OilProduction: 1,
          GasProduction: 2,
          NGLProduction: 3,
        },
      },
    ];
```

Expected design of the table:

| parameter | 2023 | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| oil production | 0 | 1 |
| gas production | 0 | 2 |
| NGL production | 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the best, but it gets the job done!

- We can create a `hashMap` of the values on the array with the key being the `year` and the values.
- Then we create an array containing the titles and their appropriate key in the API
- then we create the final array which we send to prime ng table
- Note, we just need to provide the template in the HTML for prime ng table, we have three `tr` elements, we only need one which will be used for all the rows!

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  cars: any[];
  carsFinal: any[];
  columns = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cars = [
      {
        Year: 2023,
        InputData: {
          OilProduction: 0,
          GasProduction: 0,
          NGLProduction: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        Year: 2024,
        InputData: {
          OilProduction: 1,
          GasProduction: 2,
          NGLProduction: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        Year: 2025,
        InputData: {
          OilProduction: 1,
          GasProduction: 2,
          NGLProduction: 3,
        },
      },
    ];
    const propArray = [
      { title: 'Oil Production', key: 'OilProduction' },
      { title: 'Gas Production', key: 'GasProduction' },
      { title: 'NGL Production', key: 'NGLProduction' },
    ];
    const hashMap = {};
    this.cars.forEach((item: any) => {
      hashMap[item.Year] = item.InputData;
    });
    this.columns = Object.keys(hashMap);
    this.carsFinal = propArray.map((data: any) => {
      const item = {
        ...data,
      };
      this.columns.forEach((column: string) => {
        item[column] = hashMap[column][item.key];
      });
      return item;
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="ui-table-wrapper">
  <p-table [value]="carsFinal">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>parameter</th>
        <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ column }}</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ car.title }}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ car[column] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-demo-d9zlaq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: what if i have to use dynamic columns , like 2023 to 50 100 records.. can we pass years dynamically?